# React Router how to dynamically change search part of url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hey I have custom hook for handling page change in pagination. It using `history.push` in this hook I would like to only replace `page="1"` part of the search. So I won't override the rest of the search
I'm using react router `5.1.2`

usePagination

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const usePagination = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const onPageChange = (page: number) => {
    console.log('current history pathname in usePagination', history.location.search);
    history.push({
      pathname: history.location.pathname,
      search: `page=${page}`,
    });
  };

  return {
    onPageChange,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve all other query search parameters then you can do a string replace using regex `/(page=)\d*/i` on the current `search` value.

```
search.replace(/(page=)\d*/i, `$1${page}`)
```

This captures a group, "page=" and matches the current page value to replace. Forward the captured group to the result (`$1`) and inject the new page value. `$1${page}` resolves back to `page=N` where `N` is the specified page number

Updated hook code

```
export const usePagination = () => {
  const { location: { pathname, search }, push } = useHistory();

  const onPageChange = page => {
    push({
      pathname,
      search: search.replace(/(page=)(\d*)/i, `$1${page}`)
    });
  };

  return {
    onPageChange
  };
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-how-to-dynamically-change-search-part-of-url]